# Can I safely look at my Resin printer screen while it's printing?

Tags: lcd-screen

I have an Elegoo Saturn resin 3D printer. I'm getting floating pieces of resin in my vat that 100% aren't just pieces that have broken off of a print (I found a huge piece in the VAT that absolutely couldn't have come from any part of my model). This was from a freshly cleaned VAT and the piece couldn't have been in the bottle as I would have noticed when pouring it out.

[image]

Can I remove my vat and build plate and run a print dry. And look directly at the screen while it's printing, to see if there is any damage or light bleed. Or if there is some kind of corruption in my file that's causing it to create floating blocks of resin from geometry that shouldn't exist?

I'm more concerned about damage to my eyes from looking directly at the LCD than damage to the screen. I've got a welding mask that should filter out any UV, but it might make if difficult for me to see if there is a problem.

Comment: The cover blocks UV light. A sheet of paper like fred_dot_u mentioned is a good idea for reducing the intensity too. For extra protection you can record a video of the empty print with a phone/camera and look at it after it is finished.

Answer (score 3):

Your printer has a cover that blocks UV light from getting into the resin vat, but also prevents it from damaging your eyes. There should be sufficient illumination passing through that filtering for you to determine flaws in your LCD panel.

I'm not intimately familiar with that model and my Elegoo Mars has a test pattern that is a non-filled rectangle. To test my panel, I created a 1 mm block model to cover the entire bed size and "test printed" it in the manner you've described.

[image: LCD test panel]

As you can see in the photo, I placed a sheet of paper over the LCD panel to get a clearer visualization of the now-obvious damaged LCD.